# PHP - changing time with php and tpl in CScart

Tags: php, datetime, time, smarty, cs-cart

In my `CScart` application I use **.tpl template file** to dipslay some input data.

In the application settings, there is a default format for displaying it like `'%H:%M'` which I do not want to change. I want to force it just in one view to view seconds.

But as I am pretty new with CScart and .tpl files, this is line:

```
{$log.timestamp|date_format:"`$settings.Appearance.date_format`, `$settings.Appearance.time_format`"}
```

Which is displaying: **11/04/2022, 21.38**

I want it to be displayed with seconds.. Reference: https://currentmillis.com/

Tried of replacing second part of the code with: `date('h:i:s');`, but no success.

Can someone help, what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems like this is actually using php [date_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php) to display the time. I would, replace "`$settings.Appearance.time_format`" with something like "H:i:s".

Why don't you try this line, and see what happens

```
{$log.timestamp|date_format:"`$settings.Appearance.date_format`, 'H:i:s'"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
{$log.timestamp|date_format:"`$settings.Appearance.date_format`, %I:%M:%S"}
```